# Aristotle's Metaphysics - dative as predicate

Tags: ancient-greek, dative, aristotle, predicate

Aristotle's Metaphysics 981a19-20:

> οὐ γὰρ ἄνθρωπον ὑγιάζει ὁ ἰατρεύων ἀλλ᾽ ἢ κατὰ συμβεβηκός, ἀλλὰ Καλλίαν ἢ Σωκράτην ... ᾧ συμβέβηκεν **ἀνθρώπῳ** εἶναι.

My translation:

> For the doctor doesn’t cure a man, except accidentally, but [he cures] Callias or Socrates ... to whom it is happened to be **a man**.

Why **ἀνθρώπῳ** as a predicate is dative?

It is notable that in the Latin translation, the equivalent word is accusative:

> cui esse **hominem** accidit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[συμβαίνω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dsumbai%2Fnw) in the sense "happen to" (section A.III.b of the LSJ entry) takes the dative for the person something happens to. In this sentence, the dative it takes is the relative pronoun ᾧ: "to whom it happens". The copula εἶναι requires that its predicate should appear in the same case as whatever word it's being equated with; most often this is the nominative, but when that word is in a different case for some reason, the predicate of εἶναι will still agree with it. So ᾧ is dative because of συμβέβηκεν, and ἀνθρώπῳ is dative because of ᾧ.

Comment: Could you please refer me some grammar book on this agreement?

Comment: @AliNikzad I'm not finding examples in Smyth or Goodwin for some reason, but here's a discussion in Thompson's *Syntax of Attic Greek* (p. 13, sec. 18): https://books.google.ca/books?id=GfEIAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: (( παντὶ προσήκει ἄρχοντι φρονίμῳ εἶναι )). Exactly the same example. Thank you so much.